# How do you call your columns that contains a part of an uri

Tags: php, mysql

English isn't my first language so i can't come up with a good name. For example (an easy one) the page 'About Us', how do you call the column in the database that contains 'about-us'. I'm already searching for this word for a few years, never found a clear answer.
Example:

```
Table: pages
Columns:
`name`      `????`

Values:
About us    about-us
```

What is a good name for the ???? column, everyone seems to use something random like 'title' or 'slug'.

Comment: Its not clear what you are after? MySQL column name or something else?

Comment: Yeah, Mysql column name. I'll clear the post up

Comment: Ok, so do you mean: how to write a query which has column names like that? If so, you could use a backtick ` operator around the name.

Comment: No, i mean what is the name of the column that contains 'about-us'

Comment: I see no point in here. Why would there be a database table column for "About us"?

Comment: +1 for `path`, although that is maybe more than what you are after, since it can be more than one level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for an understandable column name to hold the short title of pages in your website.

"slug" is jargon in WordPress, Joomla!, and other CMSs for a fragment of a URL, as so:

```
 http://my.web.site/pages/slug
```

So calling your column a slug makes sense in the parlance of those software packages.

"title" is, of course, the information that goes into the `<TITLE/>` part of the `<HEAD/>` of the web page.

It seems to me that "slug" is a good choice for you.  "urlfragment" might be OK too.